# regex- html tag match printing tags along

Tags: regex

I was doing a regex to do Html tag match, It all looks good code is something like this.

```
var tag = "accountName";
var regex = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\/" + tag + ">";
var regexg = new RegExp(regex,"g");
var testRE = text.match(regexg);
return testRE;
```

So if i run this with the test string  input somewhere containing the input :

```
<accountName>Rahul Raina</accountName>
```

the output I get is correct except that i get the tags along.

```
<accountName>Rahul Raina</accountName>
```

What i need is only : `Rahul Raina`

Comment: obligatory link to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/138256

Comment: so that means i can't ??

Comment: you can 'kind of' do it, it depends. if you are sure that the text within the tags won't contain other markup then you should be ok - see answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead of match:

```
var tag = "accountName";
var regex = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\/" + tag + ">";
var regexg = new RegExp(regex,"g");
regexg.exec("<accountName>Rahul Raina</accountName>")[1]; // this equals 'Rahul Raina'
```

should give you what you need